# How to dump data of linked tables without their primary key?

Tags: database, mysql

Using MySQL 5.5, I have 3 linked tables :

```
table_1 :

| id | some_data |

table_2 :

| id | table_1_id | other_data |

table_3 :

| id | table_2_id | data_again |
```

**Here's my problem :**

1. I used to have a single database called DB1.
2. On 1 april, the database has been duplicated: DB1 and DB2
3. DB1 has been used for a while by the "Application layer V1" and DB2 has been used for a while by the "Application layer V2"
4. Today, I want to kill "Application layer V1" and DB1 **but** I want to insert the values of DB1 (from april until now) into DB2

How can I do that? The IDs of DB1 (table_1, table_2 and table_3) are alreay used in DB2...

For example, can I use mysqldump to generate inserts without primary keys, but still with the links between tables (a transaction?)

Comment: Explain little bit more please.

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: @Nicolas not only would new ids be required for each of the tables, these new ids would also have to be updated within the linked tables.  The reason for the updated links is to prevent the possible collision of table IDs from DB2.

Comment: @Nicolas do each of the tables have a date field?  Would it be possible to add an extra column to the tables?